# Getting a 404 Error when running a fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-sheets, fetch

I am currently trying to connect my website form to google sheets and am getting a status 404 error when trying to run it.

This is my code for the action I want to happen when the user clicks submit:

```
const scriptURL = '<GoogleSheetsScriptID>';
const form = document.forms['priceForm'];
console.log(form);

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => alert("You have successfully submitted."))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

I know my google sheets script ID is correct. The problem seems to be coming from where the information is actually being posted from because the 404 status error is shown next to my websites URL (not the google sheets script URL in the fetch). I am writing this code in squarespace so that could be part of the problem?

Comment: Have you published your web app with permissions for anyone to be able to call it?

Comment: Problem solved, irrelevant now.